# Character alternating between his thoughts and reading a book

Tags: style

I am working on a short story which begins with the main character reading the lines of a book, and while he is reading, he often gets distracted by his won thoughts. He alternates between his thoughts and reading. **I am writing the story in first person**. Since the lines of the book and his thoughts both have significance in the story, I wish to communicate both to the reader. How can I do this so that the reader is able to distinguish between his thoughts and lines of the book. I would appreciate if someone can also point me to an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think emphasis can be very helpful. You need to make sure the reader knows when is he reading actions, when thoughts and when book. For example:

> I went on and read the book "*I looked through the sky and there I saw it, a great bird...*" My bird, I still wonder sometimes where it went. Another sip from my coffee to continue. "*I thought it's all gone*".

Most of what I've read used the same font for thoughts and actions. A lot of them use emphasis when a flashback occurs. It's usually used to defer two narratives told one within another, like you have.